# How to use MapStruct @Mapping and @Mappings properly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct

hi my problem is when i do `mvn clean package` to build .jar files, i got some error that looked like this :

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Cactus/Documents/GitHub/Microservice/b2b/b2b-warehouse/src/main/java/com/bit/microservices/b2b/warehouse/mapper/ICategoryBpsjMapper.java:[27,33] No property named "createdDate" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "reasonDeleted"?
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Cactus/Documents/GitHub/Microservice/b2b/b2b-warehouse/src/main/java/com/bit/microservices/b2b/warehouse/mapper/ICategoryBpsjMapper.java:[27,33] No property named "createdDate" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "reasonDeleted"?
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.438 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-11-30T10:55:21+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project b2b-warehouse: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Cactus/Documents/GitHub/Microservice/b2b/b2b-warehouse/src/main/java/com/bit/microservices/b2b/warehouse/mapper/ICategoryBpsjMapper.java:[27,33] No property named "createdDate" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "reasonDeleted"?
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Cactus/Documents/GitHub/Microservice/b2b/b2b-warehouse/src/main/java/com/bit/microservices/b2b/warehouse/mapper/ICategoryBpsjMapper.java:[27,33] No property named "createdDate" exists in source parameter(s). Did you mean "reasonDeleted"?
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

but when i run my project through Boot Dashboard with right click and start my project it run normally. and my api work fine. i do some try.

first trying my code is looked like below, i have mapper file that looked like this :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ICategoryBpsjMapper {

    ICategoryBpsjMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(ICategoryBpsjMapper.class);

    @Mappings({ 
        @Mapping(target = "createdDate", dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
        @Mapping(target = "modifiedDate",dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")})
    CategoryBpsjResponseDto entityToDto(CategoryBPSJ entity);

    CategoryBPSJ DTOEntity(CategoryBPSJDto dto);
    
    CategoryBPSJ updateEntityFromDto(CategoryBPSJDto dto, @MappingTarget CategoryBPSJ entity);
    
    List<CategoryBpsjResponseDto> entityToDto(List<CategoryBPSJ> entityList);
    
    List<CategoryBPSJ> DTOEnity(List<CategoryBPSJDto> dtoList);

}
```

and here is my entity :

```
@Data
@Entity
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@ToString(of = {"id"})
@Table(name = "msCategoryBPSJ", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(name = "uk_categoryBPSJName", columnNames = { "categoryBPSJName" })})
public class CategoryBPSJ extends AuditField implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8062436315663828938L;

    @Schema(description = "Id merupakan primary key dan harus disertakan ketika edit, tipe datanya Long", example = "0", required = true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Schema(description = "kode kategori pengiriman", example = "BPSJCTH1", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    private String categoryBPSCode;

    @Schema(description = "nama kategori pengiriman", example = "Toko/Gudang Tujuan Tutup", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    private String categoryBPSJName;
    
}
```

and here is my extended AuditField class :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdDate", "modifiedDate", "isDeleted" }, allowGetters = true, allowSetters = false)
public class AuditField implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6025082509703710749L;

    @Schema(description = "Status di hapus", example = "false", required = false)
    public Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @Schema(description = "Alasan di hapus", example = "apa pun alasannya", required = false)
    public String reasonDeleted = "";

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedDate;
    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;
    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;

}
```

and here is my DTO AuditFieldDto class :

```
@Data
public class CategoryBpsjResponseDto extends AuditFieldDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -422185482845439241L;

    @Schema(description = "Id merupakan primary key dan harus disertakan ketika edit, tipe datanya Long", example = "0", required = true)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Schema(description = "kode kategori pengiriman", example = "BPSJCTH1", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    public String categoryBPSCode;

    @Schema(description = "nama kategori pengiriman", example = "Toko/Gudang Tujuan Tutup", required = true)
    @NotBlank(message = "Tidak Boleh Kosong")
    public String categoryBPSJName;

}
```

and here is my AuditFieldDto class :

```
@Data
public class AuditFieldDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3758121148184815303L;

    @Schema(description = "Status di hapus", example = "false", required = false)
    public Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @Schema(description = "Alasan di hapus", example = "apa pun alasannya", required = false)
    public String reasonDeleted = "";

    private String createdDate;
    
    private String modifiedDate;
    
    private String createdBy;
    
    private String modifiedBy;

}
```

As you can see the AuditField and AuditFieldDto have the same field, but when i do run `mvn clean package` it give me COMPILATION ERROR like the top of my question mentioned. in the error message it seems to mapstruct cannot find the field properly. Then i try to remove @Mappings and @Mapping annotation line, the build is success. seems fishy.. because when i run with Boot Dashboard is working fine with those annotation.

here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.bit.microservices</groupId>
        <artifactId>b2b</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>b2b-warehouse</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.bit.microservices.b2b</groupId>
    <name>b2b-warehouse</name>
    <description>B2B Warehouse Service</description>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <url>http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>Pivotal Software, Inc.</name>
        <url>http://www.spring.io</url>
    </organization>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <lombok.version>1.18.16</lombok.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bit.microservices</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bit.b2b</groupId>
            <artifactId>security</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.classgraph/classgraph -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.classgraph</groupId>
            <artifactId>classgraph</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.90</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.modelmapper/modelmapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>13</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <target>13</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- other annotation processors -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What i missed in my project if i want to use @Mappings and @Mapping when i build my project to .jar files with `mvn clean package`?

Comment: You should probably post your pom file. It looks like you may not have lombok setup properly.

Comment: ohh sorry hopey one, i just updated my question, it seems i already add lombok annotation processor on mapstruct plugins path

Comment: Presuming you're using a modern version of Java, you don't need `@Mappings`. It's purpose is to hold multiple copies of the `@Mapping` annotation, which is _repeatable_ and can be applied directly to the target multiple times.

Comment: hi, i try your solution, so my code in my mapper file wil looked like this :
 @Mapping(target = "createdDate", dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
 @Mapping(target = "modifiedDate",dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
 CategoryBpsjResponseDto entityToDto(CategoryBPSJ entity);
but the error is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the culprit here, but i am not sure why and is this the right things to do, since when i do this code, it worked. okay lets start, you can check my mapstruct version at my question, and here is how i fixed this :

first of all, in my AuditField and AuditFieldDto, as you can see i have 2 field that written in "`public`" data type, at first i write all of my field in public but then my friend come and refer me to make it private, but i accidentally i don't make all of it private, the two fields named `public Boolean isDeleted;` and `public String reasonDeleted;` is public, that's why the error go through them, they work fine and the error go to my another line that written in private.

and i just random miserably changed their data type back into public, as you can see there is 4 field that written in private fields, they are

```
@CreatedDate
private Date createdDate;
@LastModifiedDate
private Date modifiedDate;
@CreatedBy
private String createdBy;
@LastModifiedBy
private String modifiedBy;
```

so i changed all of them into public in my AuditFieldDto and AuditField class, the complete of code of my AuditField class is looked like this :

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "createdDate", "modifiedDate", "isDeleted" }, allowGetters = true, allowSetters = false)
public class AuditField implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6025082509703710749L;

    @Schema(description = "Status di hapus", example = "false", required = false)
    public Boolean isDeleted;

    @Schema(description = "Alasan di hapus", example = "apa pun alasannya", required = false)
    public String reasonDeleted;

    @CreatedDate
    public Date createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    public Date modifiedDate;
    @CreatedBy
    public String createdBy;
    @LastModifiedBy
    public String modifiedBy;

}
```

it's apply the same for my AuditFieldDto class, which is looked like this :

```
@Data
public class AuditFieldDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3758121148184815303L;

    @Schema(description = "Status di hapus", example = "false", required = false)
    public Boolean isDeleted = false;

    @Schema(description = "Alasan di hapus", example = "apa pun alasannya", required = false)
    public String reasonDeleted = "";

    public String createdDate;
    
    public String modifiedDate;
    
    public String createdBy;
    
    public String modifiedBy;

}
```

and when i do run `mvn clean package` the build is a success! and i ran the .jar files, it working! i guess why??? i stuck for days because of this. then i try to look into the generated files, you can find the generated files in your project located at `target/generated-sources/annotations` and fine the mapper class file. And here is mine, i only take one example of the generated code, since the other seems doesn't have any problem.

here is what inside the `GENERATED FILE` (we shouldn't edit this file, just for view) :

```
@Component
public class ICategoryBpsjMapperImpl implements ICategoryBpsjMapper {

    @Override
    public CategoryBpsjResponseDto entityToDto(CategoryBPSJ entity) {
        if ( entity == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        CategoryBpsjResponseDto categoryBpsjResponseDto = new CategoryBpsjResponseDto();

        if ( entity.createdDate != null ) {
            categoryBpsjResponseDto.createdDate = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" ).format( entity.createdDate );
        }
        if ( entity.modifiedDate != null ) {
            categoryBpsjResponseDto.modifiedDate = new SimpleDateFormat( "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss" ).format( entity.modifiedDate );
        }
        categoryBpsjResponseDto.isDeleted = entity.isDeleted;
        categoryBpsjResponseDto.reasonDeleted = entity.reasonDeleted;
        categoryBpsjResponseDto.createdBy = entity.createdBy;
        categoryBpsjResponseDto.modifiedBy = entity.modifiedBy;

        return categoryBpsjResponseDto;
    }

}
```

you see they access the property without get and set (i mean getter setter), i think this is the culprit that cause my error since when i marked the field as private, and if the code is written like that, they won't can be accessed. for now this is the way i solved it.

if someone have better answer, i will take their answer as accepted answer, if mine code not right or appropriate, waiting for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the [lombok-mapstruct-binding](https://mapstruct.org/faq/#can-i-use-mapstruct-together-with-project-lombok).

Comment: hi i already add the lombok-mapstruct-binding, but the compile still got the same error, i already updated my pom.xml that added lombok-mapstruct-binding

Comment: hi hopey one, i have to revert the lombok-mapstruct-binding, since that's not the solution. i think i found one, i will post it as answer while waiting for better answer